# How to connect a LED G13 Tube directly to a power socket?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led, current, light

I am trying to build my own cheap lighting for my greenhouse. I have found a couple LED tubes that would be perfect for the task, only they are supposed to be mounted on a lamp of some sort. They have two G13 plugs, one on each side of the tube. Since I'm very ignorant in electronics, how would I connect them to the power socket? I suppose I would have to buy a power plug and some wire, but that's as far as I go.

Comment: You buy a suitable G13 lamp holder and wire that to the mains. It sounds as though you should consider professional help for this project.

Comment: That would probably solve the problem, unfortunately I wasn't able to find one of the right size, they are all quite big, and they are also relatively expensive, I could just buy greenhouse lights at this point. I have found though G13 sockets, alas I have no idea on how to connect the wires since there are two of them. Also, I read around the Internet and found out about the need of a ballast, do I really need one?

Comment: This would do better on diy, the home improvement site. That said, if they are g13, and a g13 base doesn't work, then they aren't g13. Maybe a smaller size?

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't find a G13 base and was trying to understand how to wire the sockets myself. I've since been able to find a compatible G13 lamp holder though, but am now considering LED strips.

Comment: Are you not in the US? G13 bases are a dollar a piece at a big box store like Home Depot. You cold solder on some wire as a pig tail connector.

Comment: I am not, hailing from Italy. I was able to find G13 bases at the store but they were all very big and pricey, found one on the Internet for cheap tho

Comment: @Passerby I believe I misinterpreted your comment. I thought you were referring to a whole lamp holder, and not to just single bases. I suppose I would have to buy two of them, found them on Amazon for cheap. Alas, I have no idea on how to wire them to a plug. If it was just one it probably wouldn't be too hard to figure out, but it's the two connectors that trouble me.

Comment: @Valfodr depends on how your specific led tubes need to be wired. Sometimes they are single ended, so only one g13 base needs to be wired up, the other side would just hold the tube in place. Make sure you do not get shunted g13 bases just in case.

Answer (score 1):

> I have found a couple LED tubes that would be perfect for the task,

I highly doubt some G13 tubes are "perfect for the task". Especially if it has a frosted tube that will block half the photons. A clear tube can block 10% of the photons.

---

There are two main criteria when it comes to grow light LEDs, photons per watt and spectrum.

Plants mostly like dark red (660 nm) and some dark blue (450 nm).

[image]

Warm white (2700K) has more red than cool white (5000K).
High CRI (90+) has more red than low CRI (70).

Many growers will go for the cooler white because they a higher luminous efficacy (lm/W).  A quality 5000K LED may have 180 lm/W where a 2700K may have only 140 lm/W.  Plants do not care about lumens, only the number of photons.  A 2700K emits almost as many photons as the 5000K when the LED under the phosphor is the same LED in both light sources.

[image]

[image]

---

**2700K 97 CRI**

[image]

---

The plant on the left is growing under 5700K the one on the right 3000K.  The one in the middle was planted about 1 week after the other two.

[image]

---

For most photons per watt, I recommend the inexpensive Bridgelux EB Gen2 or the Samsung F-Series strips powered with a Mean Well HLG LED driver.

This is seven $7, 3000K Bridgelux BXEB-L0560Z-30E2000-C-B3 strips
Driven with a Mean Well HLG-240H-C1400B. 
You can find a DIY guide at [LED Gardener](http://ledgardener.com/diy-guides/). You do not need to mount the strips to an aluminum bar.  I just screw down the strips at the ends to the aluminum frame.  No heatsink was needed with the Bridgelux.  The Samsung you just reduce the current a little bit until the temperature is below 50°c.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I had made further research in the meantime. I were able to find a good lamp holder for the LED tube, but ran across LED strips and it looked like a much more practical solution already. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. Only I can't really make our from your answer whether you are recommending warm light or cool light. I was going to opt for natural light in the beginning. Check this out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grow_light#LEDs_(Light_Emitting_Diodes)

Comment: It would seem that while red light has been shown to promote flowering and fruiting, blue light would seem to promote vegetative growth. Green light though has also been shown to be beneficial, making natural light the "best" option... ? I thought that while one may want to go for white warm light while fruiting and cool for growing, I couldn't go wrong going for natural light (somewhere in the middle). Again, this is all based on very little scientific knowledge on the matter and extrapolation from various sources, so I might be awfully wrong somewhere.

Comment: The question now is what temp. I should go for: warm (around 2700K) or natural (5000K), given that cool (6700K) seems to not fare well from your pictures. If I had to hazard a guess, in most LED professional greenhouse lighting there is a much smaller number or blue LEDs than there are red ones. I'm guessing that perhaps  cool LEDs have too much blue light? With that being said, I guess the main argument I have found this far supporting natural over warm would be the beneficial effect of green light.

http://hortsci.ashspublications.org/content/39/7/1617.full.pdf+html

Comment: This is all very interesting and detailed, but how does it answer the OP's question "How to connect a LED G13 Tube directly to a power socket"?

Comment: @brhans my point is a G13 tube is not the way to go making it moot.

Comment: Go as low as you can for the CCT and as high as possible with the CRI.  The recommended economic and readily available strips would be 2700K to 3000K at 80CRI. I have made my own strips using ≈1750K and 98 CRI. You will probably have a difficult time finding Bridegelux in Italy so should try to find the Samsung F-Series Gen3 3000K CRI 80.  Use the 23V, not the dual row 46V they get too hot. The veg/flower comes from cannabis growers and they are too high to understand. The blue "veg" is to reduce elongation but too much blue also stunts growth.

Comment: The 2004 Hortsci paper is controversial.  The thing about green is much is reflected (that why plants appear green) and also not much is absorbed by the plant.  This is good for transmittance where the photons travel through the leaves do to leaves lower in the canopy.  You should look for blue red ratio for the species of plants you are growing.   The optimal spectrum for lettuce is different than most other plant spices.  I help Kevin Folta's department with their LED research, see: https://www.intechopen.com/books/advances-in-photosynthesis-fundamental-aspects/the-guiding-force-of-photons

Comment: And you're almost certainly correct. My point is that you've answered a [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) question, not an electronics one. It's a great answer - I just don't think it fits *here*... I'm tempted to go and ask a question about grow light spectrum over there so that this answer has an appropriate home ... ;)

Comment: @brhans I'm sorry, I would continue the discussion elsewhere if I knew how, but I'm new to the forum. Although the discussion kind of skewed, I believe that the question was answered nonetheless. The best way to connect a G13 Led Tube to the power socket would be to get a hold of a G13 lamp holder, which isn't that easy to find in Italy but I eventually did, so someone in the US shouldn't have a problem. As to wiring a lamp holder yourself, I don't know how to do that and nobody here has had any answer in that regard, but a lamp holder should be cheap enough to not justify that effort.

Comment: @Misunderstood Sorry, took me a while to read through the very interesting document you sent. Going back to the task at hand, I have looked around for natural light LED's, and most cheap ones don't even indicate CRI and CCT. I was able to find one with very good values but the price was up there. I believe the cheapest way to go would probably be to just buy a blue led strip and a red led strip and figure out the correct ratio for the plant I'm growing (which also seems to be the way most low-cost greenhouse lighting solutions go for). What do you think about that?